# The default apache site does not show up when i include httpd-vhosts.conf! Whats the problem?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-proxy

I am trying to add two virtual hosts to apache.

In httpd.conf i uncomment these lines:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And i add these to httpd-vhosts.conf;

```
<Directory "C:/dev/cfusion">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:80

<virtualhost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "C:\dev\cfusion"
    ServerName cfusion
    ProxyRequests Off  
<proxy *>  
    Order deny,allow  
    Allow from all  
</Proxy>  
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/cfusion/  
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/cfusion/  
    ErrorLog "logs/cfusion.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/cfusion.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<virtualhost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "C:\dev\cfusion"
    ServerName railo
    ProxyRequests Off  
<proxy *>  
    Order deny,allow  
    Allow from all  
</Proxy>  
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/railo/  
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/railo/  
    ErrorLog "logs/railo.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/railo.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

When i comment the Include, i see the default apache site, otherwise i get an 500 internal server error. Whats the problem?

When i un-comment

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/railo/
```

then i dont get the 500 error anymore, but the proxying does not work :(

Comment: You're getting a 500 error?  Well, what does your error log say?

Answer (score 3):

While probably not the source of your problem, this looks like an error:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

That second line should be:

```
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
```

Comment: yes i have incorrectly added a wrong line but my httpd.conf is fine.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the xml tags, which begin lowercase and end in uppercase.

i.e. `<proxy *> ... </Proxy>`

I have no Apache here to test, but give it a try

Comment: does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Some things you can try:

1. Don't use the DocumentRoot directive, you don't need it for vhosts using proxy.
2. Remove `<proxy *> ... </proxy>` directives. This is not used for reverse proxy.
3. Define a ServerAlias directive and a ProxyTimeout
4. Put the ProxyRequests before ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse

Hope it works.

Comment: Your suggestions do not help

Comment: Have you tried to set the LogLevel to debug to see what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have found the error. All i had to do is un-comment the proxy submodule:

```
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```